# Problema na atualização dos resultados Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi

Olá,
Eu fiz uma tela onde tenho 4 botões é mudo o posicionamento deles de acordo com um Random, funciona mais as imagens na tela não atualiza.

```html
procedure TfrmJogo01.AtualizaImagemTela(caminho, nomedaimagem: string;ComponenteImagem: TImage);
  var
  FileName: string;
begin
    //carrega a imagem
    FileName := caminho + nomedaimagem;
    if FileExists(FileName) then
       ComponenteImagem.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
end;
```

```html
procedure TfrmJogo01.GeraResultadoParaColuna01;
var
   Num: Byte;
   a : integer;
begin

    for a := 1 to 200 do
    begin

     Num := Random(4);

     case (Num) of

       0 :
       Begin
        //posição padrão
        AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem01.png',btnBotao01Coluna01);
        AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem02.png',btnBotao02Coluna01);
        AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem03.png',btnBotao03Coluna01);
        AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem04.png',btnBotao04Coluna01);
       End;

       1 :
       Begin
         //posiciona a imagem 02 no lugar 01
         AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem02.png',btnBotao01Coluna01);
         //manda a imagem 01 para a posição 02  que estará vazia
         AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem01.png',btnBotao02Coluna01);
       End;


        2 :
       Begin
         //posiciona a imagem 03 no lugar 01
         AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem03.png',btnBotao01Coluna01);
         //manda a imagem 01 para a posição 03  que estará vazia
         AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem01.png',btnBotao03Coluna01);
       End;

        3 :
       Begin
         //posiciona a imagem 04 no lugar 01
         AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem04.png',btnBotao01Coluna01);
         //manda a imagem 01 para a posição 04  que estará vazia
         AtualizaImagemTela('C:\SistemaJogoA\personagens\','imagem01.png',btnBotao04Coluna01);
       End;

     end;

 end;

end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só faltou acrescentar este método:

```
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Comment: Marque como resolvida :)